# Node and Express server running on the terminal but web browser says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localhost refused to connect."

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, nodemon, babel-node

This is my `Node.js` code:

```
// Using ES6 syntax is fine because we already have Babel to transpile code.
import express from 'express';
// Create an Express application.
const app = express();
// Define port number for the server.
const PORT = 400;
// When visitors make a GET request to address "/", specify the response.
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
    res.send(`Node and Express server running on port ${PORT}`)
);
// Send message to the console to confirm that the server is running on the specified port.
app.listen(PORT, () => 
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

When I use `$ npm start`, I get this:

```
> smr@1.0.0 start /Users/jaimemontoya/Desktop/SMR
> nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js
[nodemon] starting `babel-node ./index.js`
Server running on port 400
```

However, when I visit http://localhost:4000/ from a web browser, I see this:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

Any ideas to make this work from a web browser?

**UPDATE 1:**

I meant http://localhost:400

Comment: try.. http://localhost:400 or change the port

Comment: It works on PORT 406! Thank you, please write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone As you wish, but thank you very much for helping me to discover what the problem was.

Comment: ports below 1024 are privileged, it could be that.. but would show diff error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That makes sense. But thank you. Now it is working for me from web browsers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209604/discussion-between-jaime-montoya-and-lawrence-cherone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess PORT 400 was not available for me. I used `const PORT = 406;` and now when I visit http://localhost:406/, it works, I get this message:

> Node and Express server running on port 406